# can Sonarqube analyse code only on latest perforce changelists

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube5.1, sonarqube-web

can Sonarqube analyse code only on latest **perforce** changelists.I don't want code review on the whole code base as its Legacy code written 10-15 yrs back.
can you please help me here or point me to any documentation.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is the [Leak Period](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/HOME/Fixing+the+Water+Leak). I.e. you want to focus on the recent changes to the code. SonarQube is designed to help you do that.

The entire code base will be analyzed, but by default the [Quality Gate](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Quality+Gates) tests changes on new/leak period code, and the interface is designed to highlight leak period changes.